# vertical accordian menu reset active state on click

Tags: javascript, onclick, accordion

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var accordion_head = $('.accordion > li > a'),
        accordion_body = $('.accordion li > .sub-menu');

    /* accordion_head.first().addClass('active').next().slideDown('normal'); */

    accordion_head.on('click', function(event) {

        event.preventDefault();

        if ($(this).attr('class') != 'active'){
            accordion_body.slideUp('normal');
            $(this).next().stop(true,true).slideToggle('normal');
            accordion_head.removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
        }

    });

});
```

I have tried a few attempts @ getting the active accordion header to close on click but cant seem to work it out :(

Thanks in advance
Steven

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var accordion_head = $('.accordion > li > a'),
        accordion_body = $('.accordion li > .sub-menu');

    /* accordion_head.first().addClass('active').next().slideDown('normal'); */

    accordion_head.on('click', function(event) {

        event.preventDefault();

        if ($(this).attr('class') != 'active'){
            accordion_body.slideUp('normal');
            $(this).next().stop(true,true).slideToggle('normal');
            accordion_head.removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
        } else {
            accordion_body.slideUp('normal');
            accordion_head.removeClass('active');
        }

    });

});
```

After searching awhile and not being any type of voice on Javascript, I eventually figured it out. This is a working version :) for peeps like me :) enjoy

Comment: can you create fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

It appears you remove the active class from accordion_head with this line:

```
accordion_head.removeClass('active');
```

and then add it back immediately afterward with this line:

```
$(this).addClass('active');
```

I suspect you don't want to re-add the active class?

Try:

accordion_head.on('click', function(event) {

```
    event.preventDefault();

    if ($(this).attr('class') != 'active'){
        accordion_body.slideUp('normal');
        $(this).next().stop(true,true).slideToggle('normal');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }
    else {
      // Other code that applies when accordion_head is not active
      accordion_head.removeClass('active');
    }

});
```

Comment: silly question I cant post what I have tried to do grr! but on reclick active it collapses menu body but then re opens it :(